# После удаления приложения остается его старая версия

Tags: android

Случилась такая непонятка. Есть приложение. Устанавливаю его через Android Studio. Все работает как положено. Решил проверить чистую установку. Удалил приложение как полагается. Ставлю заново. Приложение при первом запуске проверяет нет ли в настройках SharedPreferences записи о предыдущей версии (что бы понять приложение ставится вновь или обновляется). И вот тут оно находит этот параметр и начинает процесс обновления. Копирует данные из старой БД в новую и т.д. Причем БД какая то старая, а не та, что была у приложения которое я удалил перед проверкой чистой установки. Захожу в системные настройки приложения. Очищаю данные. Запускаю - идет чистая установка. Удаляю. Снова ставлю в чистую - снова откуда то берутся данные старой версии. Удалял через adb shell pm uninstall. Проверял через adb после удаления - пакета такого приложения нет. Чистил SDMaid. Может есть какие мысли на этот счет? Спасибо.

Comment: есть мысль что это кривизна девайса - с подобным лично сталкивался - на одном норм удаляется, а на другом как у тебя.

Comment: @Михаил, дело в том, что с другим моим приложением такого не происходит. А именно с этим приложением и даже на другом устройстве, другого производителя... вот в чем беда

Comment: android:allowBackup="false" в манифесте

Comment: @Романыч, да точно. Был у меня такой параметр, но я его удалил, т.к. "The attribute android:allowBackup is deprecated from Android 12 and higher and may be removed in future versions..."

Comment: @Романыч, Вы можете вынести свой ответ как Ответ. Я приму его как решение, если хотите. Еще раз спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить `android:allowBackup="false"` в манифесте